# SQL Server - Construct a dynamic where clause based on the records inside a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

I have a table called `dbo.ItemTagTransactions` that looks like this:

```
PK_ID | ItemTag
1     | Filename.xlsx
2     | ABC7798
3     | {empty string}
4     | Completed
```

How do you construct a dynamic `WHERE` clause based on the values in the `ItemTag` column inside the above table? This table may have one or more records.

The query that I will be using looks like this:

```
SELECT FK_QueueItem_ItemTagTransaction 
FROM dbo.ItemTagTransactions 
WHERE TagValue = {insert dynamic where clause here}
```

And the field in the `WHERE` clause is always refering to TagValue and it can be 1 or more. It is based on a string that is delimited by a semi-colon, like this. "Filename.xlsx;ABC7798;;Completed"

Desired result is this:

```
SELECT FK_QueueItem_ItemTagTransaction 
FROM dbo.ItemTagTransactions 
WHERE TagValue = 'Filename.xlsx' 
   OR TagValue = 'ABC7798' 
   OR TagValue = '' 
   OR TagValue = 'Completed'
```

P.S. I will be using this inside a stored procedure

Comment: What are you talking about? Since you are using a stored procedure just pass a `@Variable` to your proc and `WHERE TagValue = @Variable`

Comment: I can't pass a variable because the parameters come from that table.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: yes, it should be OR, my mistake

Comment: So how to you decide on which TagValues you are looking for? Is it always 4? Can the user tick boxes? Because if you want every row in the table you don't  need a `where` clause.

Comment: The field in the WHERE clause is always refering to TagValue and it can be 1 or more. It is based on a string that is delimited by a semi-colon, like this. Filename.xlsx;ABC7798;;Completed

Comment: Well you just want a where clause like `where TagValue in ([split my ; delimited string])`. So if you google splitting a delimited string in SQL.

Comment: I have a function that splits a delimited string in SQL but it outputs a table, what should the output of my function be instead?

Comment: Tables are perfect for use with an `in` clause. `where tagValue in (select Value from SplitStringTable)`

Comment: @Dale Burrel please write this as an answer so I can upvote it. You were the first one to mention the answer.

Comment: @thecodeexplorer - thats very kind of you :) but MarcinJ has also given that answer, so give it to him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is semi-colon delimited, you can simply replace those semi-colons with `', '` and wrap it around with `'` to form valid list of values:

```
DECLARE @sampleInput NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Filename.xlsx;ABC7798;;Completed'

DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Query = 'SELECT FK_QueueItem_ItemTagTransaction FROM dbo.ItemTagTransactions WHERE TagValue IN (' 
           + CONCAT('N''', REPLACE(@sampleInput, ';', ''',N'''), '''')
           + ')'

PRINT @Query
```

It will output:

```
SELECT FK_QueueItem_ItemTagTransaction FROM dbo.ItemTagTransactions WHERE TagValue IN (N'Filename.xlsx',N'ABC7798',N'',N'Completed')
```

If you want to execute the query and store the results for further processing, create a temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #results
(
    FK_QueueItem_ItemTagTransaction INT -- adjust the
);

INSERT INTO #results
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

If you have a string split function that returns a table, then it's even easier, you simply go with

```
SELECT FK_QueueItem_ItemTagTransaction 
  INTO #results -- for further processing
  FROM dbo.ItemTagTransactions 
 WHERE TagValue IN (SELECT Value 
                      FROM dbo.mySplitStringFunction(@sampleInput))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Dynamic Sql. Multiple Tag Values must be separated with inverted commas like the InputString as shown below.

```
  declare @dynamicsql nvarchar(max),@inputstring nvarchar(max)='''ABC101170'',''dfg101264'''
    select @dynamicsql='select * from table 
    where tagvalue in('+@inputstring+')'
print @dynamicsql
exec sp_executesql @dynamicsql
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

```
SELECT FK_QueueItem_ItemTagTransaction 
FROM dbo.ItemTagTransactions 
WHERE TagValue IN (SELECT ItemTag FROM dbo.ItemTagTransactions)
```

Try this...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **[`table-valued parameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)** as

```
CREATE TYPE MyType AS TABLE (AValues VARCHAR(50));

CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
  @AVariable MyType READONLY
AS
  SELECT *
  FROM T
  WHERE ItemTag IN (SELECT AValues FROM @AVariable);

CREATE TABLE T(
  PK_ID INT,
  ItemTag VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1, 'Filename.xlsx'),
(2, 'ABC7798'),
(3, '{empty string}'),
(4, 'Completed');

DECLARE @Var MyType;

INSERT INTO @Var VALUES
('Filename.xlsx'), ('Completed');

EXEC dbo.MyProc @Var;
```

**Returns:**

```
+-------+---------------+
| PK_ID |    ItemTag    |
+-------+---------------+
|     1 | Filename.xlsx |
|     4 | Completed     |
+-------+---------------+
```

See how it's working on this **[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8c723291e0091edbb537c4fbaf1f95e2)**

You can pass a string, and just

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
  @AVariable VARCHAR(300)
AS
  SELECT *
  FROM T CROSS APPLY 
       (SELECT Value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@AVariable, ',')) TT --You can use semi-colon ; instead of ,
  WHERE T.ItemTag = TT.Value;
```

**[Second Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=872d1e36720144c90a524ee424486aa5)**

but it's more safe to use table-valued parameter as the string may contains `,`.